# Java Quiz - not accepting users input when correct

Tags: java

```
    private void startGame() {
        System.out.println("Exercises must be completed as quickly as possible.");
        System.out.println("You have to solve 3 exercises.");
        System.out.println("Be as fast as you can!\n");

        Instant startTime = Instant.now();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            Exercise exercise = Exercise.getRandomExercise();
            System.out.print(exercise);
            int guess = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
            exercise.solve(guess);
            if (!exercise.solve(guess)) {
                System.out.println("\nYou have made a mistake.");
                System.out.println("More luck next time.\n");
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();

        Instant endTime = Instant.now();
        Duration timeElapsed = Duration.between(startTime, endTime);
        double seconds = timeElapsed.toMillis() / 1000.0;

        Record record = new Record(seconds);
        System.out.println("You needed " + seconds + " seconds.");
        if (recordList.add(record)) {
            System.out.println("You have set a new record!");
            System.out.print("Your name: ");
            record.setName(scanner.nextLine());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }


}



import java.util.Random;

class Exercise {
    private String question;
    private String solution;

    private Exercise(String question, String solution) {
        this.question = question;
        this.solution = solution;
    }


    public static Exercise getRandomExercise() {

        records s1 = new records();
        records s2 = new records();
        records s3 = new records();

        // RECORDS OF QUESTIONS
        s1 = setQuestion(s1, "What is the largest bone in the human body? \n Choose 1 for Femur \n Choose 2 for Tibia \n Choose 3 for Palatine Bone \n Choose 4 for Tongue \n");
        s2 = setQuestion(s2, "What is the capital of Albania? \n Choose 1 for Shkoder \n Choose 2 for Tirana \n Choose 3 for Durres \n Choose 4 for Rome \n");
        s3 = setQuestion(s3, "The beaver is the national emblem of which country? \n Choose 1 for England \n Choose 2 for America \n Choose 3 for Canada \n Choose 4 for Texas \n");

        // RECORDS OF ANSWERS
        s1 = setCorrectAnswer(s1, 1);
        s2 = setCorrectAnswer(s2, 2);
        s3 = setCorrectAnswer(s3, 3);

        // ARRAY CONTAINING THE QUESTION WITH THE CORRESPONDING CORRECT ANSWER
        String[][] questions = {
                {getQuestion(s1), getCorrectAnswer(s1)},
                {getQuestion(s2), getCorrectAnswer(s2)},
                {getQuestion(s3), getCorrectAnswer(s3)}};


        Random random = new Random();
        int index = random.nextInt(5);
        String question;
        String solution;

        if (index == 0) {
            System.out.println(questions[0][0]);
            question = questions[0][0];
            solution = questions[0][1];

        } else if (index == 1) {
            System.out.println(questions[1][0]);
            question = questions[1][0];
            solution = questions[1][1];

        } else {
            System.out.println(questions[2][0]);
            question = questions[2][0];
            solution = questions[2][1];
        }
        return new Exercise(question, solution);
    }

    public boolean solve(int guess) {
        return solution.equals(guess);
    }


    private static String getQuestion(records s) {
        return s.question;
    }

    public static String getCorrectAnswer(records s) {
        return String.valueOf(s.correctanswer);
    }


    // SETTER METHODS
    public static records setQuestion(records s, String question) {
        s.question = question;
        return s;
    }

    public static records setCorrectAnswer(records s, int correctanswer) {
        s.correctanswer = correctanswer;
        return s;
    }



}
```

I've created an array with the records containing the question with the corresponding correct answer. When running the following code, if the user enters the correct answer, it takes it as if the user entered the wrong answer. I want the program to be able to see that the user has entered the answer correctly

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You compare String with Integer in solve method of Exercise . This can never return true because the type of the two objects are different